# JS e HTML5: Barra de Countdown so funciona "na tela"

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar, countdown

Estou implementando uma pequena barra de progresso (.progressbar) que na verdade funciona como uma "barra de contagem regressiva" (é uma barra de progresso invertida, ela começa cheia e vai reduzindo) e vai funcionar como um controle de expiracao da sessao (ao terminar o tempo - o JS faz o reload da pagina e como a sessao vai estar expirada ela é bloqueada)

o controle de sessao esta funcionando OK - que é o mais importante - mas um problema tem me perturbado - a animacao da barra nao esta acompanhando corretamente o tempo - SE O USUARIO NAO FICAR NA TELA (q é um dos motivos de implementar isso - caso o usuario "esqueça a janela aberta" - o sistema cuida de fechar ela sozinha para nao expor os dados - mesmo que outro usuario nao tenha como "acessar" mais o sistema ja que a sessao ja caiu - ele ainda teria tempo para "ver os dados expostos" - ate o timer completar.

seria algum problema no codigo ou é algo do navegador (ainda nao fiz testes maiores - acabei de implementar - so usei ela no Chrome "ultima versao")

Obrigado!

segue o JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/2tonbd5k/

*nao coloquei a linha de reload da pagina ai pra nao dar o reload no jsfiddle - mas na pagina esta ok - a questao é a animacao da barra que para quando mudamos de pagina na tela (abrimos vemos o material e vamos para outra aba) - a animacao parece que para (e enquanto ela nao "zera" ela tb nao ativa o reload).

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, "linear");
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }
};

progress(25, 25, $('#progressBar'));
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 0px;
  line-height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: isso acontece pq alguns navegadores (acho q o FF e o IE já não tem esse problema precisa confirmar) bloqueiam o setInterval quando não tem foco. Atenção que não é nem necessariamente na janela, acho que só no viewport, se fizer scroll e desaparecer a animation ela já é interrompida.

Comment: uma solução mais simples é, usar como referencia a diferença de hora no lugar do "timeleft", isso faz com que ao retornar o foco seja atualizado corretamente, e inclusive permite que o timer não seja necessariamente vincula a 1 segundo

Comment: Eu fiz esse código [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/OfficialFaintBash) uma versão do seu código porém usando webworker. A animação ficou um pouco mais grosseira pois não é animado via CSS mas se o interessar eu posso formular uma resposta explicando como funciona e quais os princípios envolvidos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques muito obrigado! a animacao por mim esta otima :D - o importante é resolver..rs - estava vendo o codigo - nao sou um expert em programacao, - mas o que me deixou louco foi o worker.js..rs

Comment: Você quer eu escreva uma resposta explicando o que fiz? Se sim, no momento estou escrevendo outra resposta então vou demorar para lhe dar um retorno.

Comment: oi @AugustoVasques, tudo bem, sem pressa - estou vendo se consigo implementar a solucao dada pelo Ricardo Pontual - parece ser algo simples (claro que é..rs) - mas to exercitando meu cerebro um pouco pra descobrir como faço para trocar o timeleft pela hora..rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloquei um timer numerico na barra so para ficar mais facil de verificar que o tempo é reduzido mesmo - mas eu pelo menos irei retirar isso inibindo a linha

```
progressBar.innerHTML = `${timeleft} seg`;
```

para fazer o redirect (e logoff da pagina) - é preciso acionar a linha, tirando as "//" e trocando o ENDEREÇO pelo endereço de redirect:

```
// window.location.replace("ENDEREÇO");
```

e vou reduzir a altura da barra para 2px - para ficar "fininha" como no exemplo original. mas a solucao é essa!!

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('#progressBar .bar');
function progress(startTime, timetotal) {
    const timeleft = timetotal + (startTime - Date.now()) / 1000 | 0;
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    const progressBarWidth = timeleft * 100 / timetotal;
    progressBar.innerHTML = `${timeleft} seg`;
    progressBar.style.width = `${progressBarWidth}%`;
    setTimeout(progress, 1000, startTime, timetotal);
  } else {
    progressBar.innerHTML = ``;
    progressBar.style.width = "0";
    // window.location.replace("ENDEREÇO");
  }
}

progress(Date.now(), 180);
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#progressBar div {
  transition: width 1s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 0px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```